# Libgdx: how to draw a rounded border around a TiledMap with dynamic dimensions?

Tags: graphics, libgdx, border

In libgdx I have a TiledMap that I fill with different Cells:

```
cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(reg1));
cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(reg2));
cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(reg...));
```

where reg is a texture region.

I render with:

```
render = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
render.setView(cam);
render.render();
```

Throughout the game, the number of columns, number of rows and size of the cells will vary, so they must remain dynamic.

Now, around this TiledMap, I want to add a rounded border. Below I am showing some examples in png of how I am planning to do it : from left to right, first is a top border, then a top-right corner, then a right border. Each of these png files has square dimensions.

[image: top border]
[image: top-right corner]
[image: right border]

What I want to achieve below, here is a zoom to the top right corner of the TiledMap:

[image]

I am planning to use these pngs as TextureRegions that I can set as cells in my TiledMap, something like that:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < numcol+2; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < numrow+2; y++) {
                Cell cell = new Cell();                 

                if (y==numrow+1) {
                    cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(b_mid_top));
                }

                if (y==0) {
                    cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(b_mid_bottom));
                }
etc.
```

I am having multiple issues with the dimension of the pngs: as I mentioned, the size of the cells may vary throughout the game. To my knowledge there is no way to resize a cell or a textureregion from a png as I would need.
So I could use Image, resize them dynamically, add them as actors to a stage and draw the stage, but I fear I might loose the benefit of using a TiledMap. Also, I would have to deal with stage coordinates on the one hand and TiledMap coordinates on the other and it doesn't sound the best approach.

So I am a bit lost! 
What is the best approach to draw my border around my TiledMap?
I am ready to abandon any of my current ideas for a better one. I am  not very experienced with Libgdx so sorry if I have done some silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea is good. In case the tilesize changes the bordersize changes too. You can't create a different sized tile as frame around it. In case you want to create always the same frame, you can use a simple [Ninepatch](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches) with the size of the Map.

create something like this:

```
NinePatch p = new NinePatch(texture, 5, 5, 5, 5); // the edge sizes are 5px here.
```

Inside of the render method you draw it at the size of the tilemap. you can optain the sizes from the Map object:

```
p.draw(batch, 0, 0, tilesize*tilecountx, tilesize*tilecounty);
```

If you do not liket his idea you can go for the second version. Create a new `TiledMap` with the boarder as tiles you need to copy the whole Tilemap with an offset of 1 tile (since you need to have 1 tile space) and create a new tilemap with 2 rows and cols more.

Should look for example like this:

```
map = new TiledMap(); // the map with the bordercells
MapLayers layers = map.getLayers();
for (int l = 0; l < map1.getLayers().getCount(); l++) {
    // create a new layer which is bigger
    TiledMapTileLayer newlayer = new TiledMapTileLayer(
            ((TiledMapTileLayer) map1.getLayers().get(0)).getWidth() + 2,
            ((TiledMapTileLayer) map1.getLayers().get(0)).getHeight() + 2,
            (int) ((TiledMapTileLayer) map1.getLayers().get(0))
                    .getTileWidth(), (int) ((TiledMapTileLayer) map1
                    .getLayers().get(0)).getTileHeight());

    // now add the cells here
    for (int x = 0; x < newlayer.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < newlayer.getHeight(); y++) {
            //add the right tile regions here!
            if(x == 0 && y == 0){
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(first edge));
                newlayer.setCell(x, y, cell);
                continue;
            }

            if(x == newlayer.getWidth()-1 && y == 0){
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(second edge));
                newlayer.setCell(x, y, cell);
                continue;
            }
            if(x == 0 && y == newlayer.getHeight()-1){
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(third edge));
                newlayer.setCell(x, y, cell);
                continue;
            }

            if(x == newlayer.getWidth()-1 && y == newlayer.getHeight()-1){
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(fourth edge));
                newlayer.setCell(x, y, cell);
                continue;
            }

            if(x == 0){ 
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(textureregion for bottom here));
                newlayer.setCell(x, y, cell);
                continue;
            }

            if(y == 0){
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(textureregion for first col));
                newlayer.setCell(x, y, cell);
                continue;
            }

            if(x == newlayer.getWidth()-1){
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(textureregion for toprow));
                newlayer.setCell(x, y, cell);
                continue;
            }

            if(y == newlayer.getHeight()-1){
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(textureregion for last col));
                newlayer.setCell(x, y, cell);
                continue;
            }
            //last but not least if none of this fit add the tile from the old map
            //dont forget the offsett
            newlayer.setCell(x, y, ((TiledMapTileLayer)map1.getLayers().get(l)).getCell(x-1, y-1)); //map1 is the original map without the borders
        }
    }
    layers.add(newlayer);
}
```

If you really have different tilesizes i would just add an Bordertexture for every tilesize you have in case you are using the TiledMap version. If you like to resize a `Texture` take a `Sprite` for it. A Sprite offers the `.setSize(w,h)` and also extends the `TextureRegion`. To create a Static `TiledMapTile` you can also add the `Sprite` as `Texture`. **So if you take the idea use a Sprite and size it to the tile size before you create the `StaticTiledMapTile`.**

Comment: Hi Benn, thanks for your answer. I don't manage to understand what are map and map1. Is one supposed to contain the regular cells and the other the border cells?

Comment: the map1 is your original map. and the map is the new map which also contains the boarder cells. Sorry if this wasnt clear. I cant guarantee that this code works it's just a kind of extendes pseudocod to give you an idea how to manage it

Comment: Ok, I get it. It works fine for any border on the right or top of the main map (positive coordinates). But I can't manage to render borders that are on the left or below the main map (negative coordinates). How can I achieve that?

Comment: you need to Flip your texture. Else the frame is on the left side instead of the right side. In one of the cases you need to flip it horizontaly or even rotate it.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but flipping the texture is not going to allow it to be added with negative coordinates is it? It seems I cannot render anything, whatever the texture is, if x<0 or y<0

Comment: `TextureRegion.flip(boolean x, boolean y) ` mirrors the texture in the center. So flip(true,false) mirrors the texture at the x coordinate.

Comment: Got it!
Thank you for all your help, much appreciated, and have a good week end